# Is it possible to use a different gcc version inside a Conda environment?

Tags: gcc, anaconda

I have to install a package ([spatial-correlation-sampler](https://github.com/ClementPinard/Pytorch-Correlation-extension)) which calls for `gcc: >=5.3`. On my system (Linux, remote server), gcc version is `4.8.5`, and a Conda virtual environment uses the same version. Is it possible to use a different version within the virtual environment?

Comment: Just putting this here in case it helps someone. It is possible to install gcc using Conda, [see][1]. But it wasn't compatible with the package I wanted to install. So in such a case, building from source might be the only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a different gcc version inside a Conda environment?

Probably yes, except if you (or your Conda environment) needs or uses some [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html). These plugins are specific to a particular version of GCC: a plugin coded for GCC 4.8 (such as my old [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/)) won't work with GCC 6. But see also [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report on [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) (which might become a successor to GCC MELT).

On Linux/x86-64, a C code compiled with GCC 4.8 would be compatible with the same code compiled with [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/), since both follow the same [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention).

For C++ code compiled with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), there could be subtle ABI or calling conventions incompatibilities (related to [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) and [exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling)).

Be also aware that Python 2 and Python 3 have *different* [foreign function interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface). Read chapters related to [extending and embedding](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/) the Python interpreter.

See also the [*Program Library HowTo*](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/), [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) and [*C++ dlopen mini-HowTo*](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/C++-dlopen/) and [*Linux Assembly HowTo*](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/) and of course [Linux From Scratch](http://linuxfromscratch.org/).

> On my system (Linux, remote server), gcc version is 4.8.5

#### [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) is [Free Software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html).

**You are allowed to compile and [install](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) a more recent GCC** from its source code on your system. **An installed GCC 4.8 can be use to build e.g. a [GCC 8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/) from its source code** (then installed into `/usr/local/bin/gcc`, then you just configure wisely your [`$PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))). You could even  do that with the unsupported [GCC 5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/).

On *recent* [Debian](https://debian.org/) or [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) you would install dependencies with something like `sudo aptitude build-dep g++` and you might also want to use [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)). You may need to download several gigabytes.

Some companies or freelancers are able (for a fee) to compile a GCC tailored for your system. I know [AdaCore](https://www.adacore.com/), but there are many others corporations or freelancers selling support on GCC. Contact [me](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/index_en.html) by email for more.

PS. On a [powerful AMD Threadripper 2970WX desktop](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/hwinfo-ours.starynkevitch.net.txt), I just built GCC 10.1 with `make -j8` and  `g++ 9.3` on Debian/Sid in 10:21.38 elapsed time,  requiring less than 7 Gbytes of disk space  (for both GCC source code and object files). Of course, I disabled the [compiler bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)). You could do the same thru `ssh` to your system (it could take an hour or two of elapsed time, because a Linux VPS has less cores so you might need to just `make -j2`).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed answer. I read through the manual and am trying to build gcc7. Can you tell me how long it takes to download the prerequisites? I ran ./contrib/download_prerequisites but there is no output and neither is it exiting. It just seems to be stuck. I'm working behind a proxy so I'm not sure if things are even getting downloaded.

Comment: No, I cannot tell you how long does it take to download things. If you have a cheap ADSL, you won't get the same bandwidth than if you have a fiber optic connection. You may need to download several gigabytes of dependencies.

Comment: Just noticed the packages are getting downloaded to srcdir, so `./contrib/download_prerequisites` is working. :)